# Get Quarkus management interface random port for RestAssured

Tags: testing, quarkus, rest-assured

I had some QuarkusTest for custom HealthChecks. With `quarkus.http.test-port` set to 0 to get a random port.
While migrating to Quarkus 3, we choose to enable the management interface.

Now, when I set `quarkus.management.test-port` to 0, RestAssured still use the port of the HTTP server so my tests failed.
I can set the port in the test but I don't know how to get the correct value.

Do you know of a way to get the management interface port ?
I can't have a fixed `quarkus.management.test-port` because sometimes it's taken by another process on integration server

Thank you

Comment: There isn't a way currently, but we can make it happen. Please open an issue on Github asking for this feature

Comment: Feature request : https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/35952